# rEFInd sees all distros except Xubuntu

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, refind

I have multiple Linux distros installed on my system (Gigabyte GA-H97M-D3H mobo, SSD as sda and HDD as sdb) any of which I can boot via rEFInd. Recently I decided to add Xubuntu 18.04 LTS. The problem is that after installing, rEFInd does not find it and offer it as a boot option. All the other distros (i.e., Linux Mint, Kubuntu, and Ubuntu) are still there and boot OK so I am thinking there is something unique about how the Xubuntu installer sets things up. I've reinstalled it from scratch several times, switched the partitions around, etc. Nothing seems to make a difference.

Is there something I am missing or is there a basic incompatibility between rEFInd and Kubuntu? All distros are, as far as I can tell, being set up the same way (i.e., installed on a partition on the sda drive).

UPDATE: It has been suggested (by kc1di) that the order of installation matters and that the xubuntu install is being presented by rEFInd as an ubuntu entry. That does not seem to be the problem as I tried installing in different orders but nothing changed. I also removed the ubuntu distro entirely. At the moment my set-up is (in order of installation):

1. Linux Mint 17 with KDE
2. Linux Mint 19.1 with Xfce
3. Xubuntu 18.04

The Xubuntu entry is still missing from the rEFInd menu.

Comment: Kubuntu, Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu are all essentially the same except for the desktop installed and the default apps. You can make one Ubuntu install and have gdm/sddm/lightdm set so you can choose your desktop at login, just in case you didn't know; no need to maintain separate installs.

Comment: Is Mint still using /EFI/ubuntu as the ESP folder? If so you only get one UEFI boot entry. I believe rEFInd is looking at the folders in the ESP. Post this above: `sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI`

Comment: @oldfred:  When running the Mint KDE distro, the command
    sudo ls  /boot/efi/EFI

returns:

    BOOT  kubuntu  refind  tools

Comment: You are not then showing any Ubuntu or Mint UEFI boot? Are they installed in UEFI boot mode? Refind will boot BIOS installs by rebooting and using UEFI one time boot entry. Normally rEFInd uses /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi file as copy of its boot file. bootx64.efi is a fallback entry and is often seen in UEFI as UEFI: hard drive or similar. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report, do not use autofix.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Done. The link to the boot-info is http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4Tdbvx5qZY/

Comment: Some context to help de-cypher what the boot-info shows:
sda2 has the Mint 17 KDE distro, sda3 has the the Xubuntu, and sda4 has Mint 19.1. What I find puzzling is that sda3 and sda4 appear to have the same structure as far as boot files go, but one appears in rEFInd and the other doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

xubuntu and Ubuntu will present the same boot signature and thus refind will not find it.  You can change the name on the boot from ubuntu to something else should work. So depending upon which one was last install you should see two ubuntu entries and one will be xubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that does not appear to be the problem. I've updated the original post to clarify why.